# How to test app connection with express, nodeJS and Mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, should.js

I've got my app properly configured, such that if I run `node app.js` everything starts up. I'm trying to test for the connection of my app is working properly using unit tests. What I have so far is:

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    port: 8080,
};
var app =  require("../app.js");
var should = require('should'); 
var assert = require("assert");
var async = require('async');

it ('tests the ok connection of the app by checking that it is listening on port 8080', function(dont) {
  request(options,app)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function (err, res) {
    res.header['location'].should.include('/')
    res.text.should.include('Listening on port 8080');
  done();
  });
});
```

I was getting the error message `Error: options.uri is a required argument`, which is why I added the `var options`. Now I'm getting error message `TypeError: Object #<Request> has no method 'get'`.

How can properly check that I have a good connection (`200`), that i'm on the right page (`'/'`) and that it is logging the message `Listening on port 8080` upon connection?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use just `request(app)` without options. Also `should` does not have `.include` you need to use `.containEql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `TypeError`, make sure you are using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) and not something else like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). The reason for this is that the module `request` does not provide the `.expect()` and other functions.

Comment: thanks for your reply - when I visit the `'/'` page it I want it to display the html I am sending it. Thus, I don't know if it is good for me to use something like `app.get('/user', function(req, res){ res.send(200); });`, since that just displays something in place of the html I want to show up. So how could I test for whatever is on the landing page?